# Include User ID in iFrame URL

Tags: php, functions, user-meta, embed, iframe

I seem to have hit a roadblock trying to figure out how to append the user ID to an embedded iFrame url address. I am using a third party app that tracks unique users (and invoices me accordingly). Unfortunately, they were unable to help me figure it out.

The embed code is: `<iframe src="https://www.hostingsite.com/../embed/?u=[get_user_id_code_should_go_here]" width="100%" height="500" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` where the ?u parameter should display the user id.

I was told that the way I would know it works is if the ID would show up in the page source. Unfortunately, I tried the `"<?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>"` and it did not work (displays exactly the text `<?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>`, but after doing a little bit of digging, I think I found out this would not be possible to begin with.

Am I supposed to include something in a template to make this work or should Wordpress handle this "out of the box"? I am running WP 5.7 with the latest version of Memberpress.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/386517/edit) to show us the code you're using to populate the `?u=...` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention!  I am terribly sorry, I believe it's plainly clear I'm new to this...which is why I appreciate your help that much more!